# How to make a real time count of how many have successfully executed in the Javascipt function?

Tags: javascript, html, counter

I want to make a real-time count of the total function of the javascript that all user can see when he visit my site.
For example, there are 3 visitors now I want to total how many successful Javascript executed they do that the count don't reset when the page refresh and are all visible to all user who visit.

html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<div class="card-profile-stats d-flex justify-content-center mt-md-5">
<div>
<span class="heading" id="count1">0</span>
<span class="badge badge-success">Count 1</span>
</div>
<div>
<span class="heading" id="count2">0</span>
<span class="badge badge-danger">Count 2</span>
</div>
<div>
<span class="heading" id="count3">0</span>
<span class="badge badge-info">Count 3</span>
</div>
<div>
<span class="heading" id="all">0</span>
<span class="badge badge-info">Total</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
function startfunc() {
    var xs = 0;
    var cb = 0;
    var fp = 0;
    $.ajax({
    url: 'urlhere.php',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    success: //some of my code here
                    
    var total = parseInt(xs) + parseInt(cb) + parseInt(fp);
    $('#count1').html(xs);
    $('#count2').html(cb);
    $('#count3').html(fp);
    $('#all').html(total);
```

Comment: I am sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I'd guess, if you add the rest of the relevant code, it turns out to be a timing problem. Updating the DOM before the ajax request has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a database that is storing the values (this would be the only way to store the total values) then you would create an interval timer that would perform the http request to get the results on frequency that is not too often.

The example I'm giving is in pure JavaScript, so it should work. You don't need jQuery for this.

**Promise Method:**

**File:** `script.js`

```js
// Code to execute when window loaded
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

   // Main function to retrieve results
   const getResults = () => {
      fetch('/url/to/getResults.php')
         .then(response => {
             const json = response.json();
             if (response.ok) {
                return json;
             }
             return json.then(data => Promise.reject(data));
         })
         .then(jsonData => {
             const total = parseInt(jsonData.xs) + parseInt(jsonData.cb) + parseInt(jsonData.fp);
             document.querySelector('#count1').innerHTML = jsonData.xs;
             document.querySelector('#count2').innerHTML = jsonData.cb;
             document.querySelector('#count3').innerHTML = jsonData.fp;
             document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML = total;
         })
         .catch(error => {
             console.log('ERROR', error);
         });
   };

   // Get an update results every 60 seconds
   const interval = setInterval(getResults, 60000);
});
```

**Async/Await Method:**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

   // Main function to retrieve results
   const getResults = async () => {
      try {
         const response = await fetch('/url/to/getResults.php');
         const responseJSON = await response.json();
         const total = parseInt(jsonData.xs) + parseInt(jsonData.cb) + parseInt(jsonData.fp);
         document.querySelector('#count1').innerHTML = jsonData.xs;
         document.querySelector('#count2').innerHTML = jsonData.cb;
         document.querySelector('#count3').innerHTML = jsonData.fp;
         document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML = total;
      } catch (error) {
         console.log('ERROR', error);
      }
   };

   // Get an update results every 60 seconds
   const interval = setInterval(await getResults, 60000);
});
```